# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

```
$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    closeClick : true,
    helpers : {
    title : {
        type : 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

This is a code for fancy box i included the entire lib folder and source folder of fancy box but i still get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the `$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox` what may be the cause of this what is the solution for this

`UPDATE`

got the code [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/)

this is all the script i used

```
    <link   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

    <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

    <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

    <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>

<!--slider-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<!--slider end-->
```

Comment: Can you show your fancybox reference libraries? Have you checked the libraries are referenced correctly?

Comment: Show us the code that you have used to include the library/source.

Comment: all lib are reference correctly because it did not show the the lib is missing it only shows the error i asked above. i updated the question i am wondering about the last update i do not have that in the code why is it missing?because i dont have that in the first place

Comment: Why you have refrenced multiple jquery library versions?

Comment: Above error means you are calling method on something which is not available. Hence you must be missing something

Comment: same error as in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26117531/1055987 I recommended you to use a single version of jQuery

Comment: i did but as you can see its now working so i asked a more details question..

Comment: @I--I : nope, it's not working because you are still including two different versions of jQuery

Comment: @JFK i did remove the version but it did not i just posted it again so everyone can see the original code please dont get me wrong

Answer (score 6):

Try

`jQuery` insted `$`, and there are two `jQuery` lib loading!!!

```
 <script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Remove one of those from header.

EDIT your script have to go like this in order to work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        closeClick : true,
        helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: remove one but still i get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in this line `$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox`

Comment: try jQuery(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox...

Comment: tried nothing happened still undefined it is defined in one of the files in source right?

Comment: you have to do that in document ready event when all js files are loaded.

Comment: it did can you explain?

Comment: It should be `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`, don't pass `($)` as an argument. The first argument in `.ready()` is the event, I think, and using `$` will overwrite the jQuery object instead

Comment: but it works now @ChenAsraf can you explain why it should not be $

Comment: so i should use `$(document).ready(function()` instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function($) `

Comment: You can use with `$` or without `$` as you wish. If there is no `$` than you call jquery by `jQuery(...`

Comment: `$` it just shot name for convenience, that you wouldn't type every time `jQuery`. You can put anything that you wont insted of `$` for example `jQuery(document).ready(function(something){ something.(".fancybox-effects-b")...`

Comment: This line of code saved my ass:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have included 2 jQuery scripts. Remove one of them

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> //remove anyone of them
```

Type in browser's console jQuery and check whether it give function or not.

Or call your script in onload or ready function()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        closeClick : true,
        helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

Here $ or jQuery variable will be consider as jQuery object. Anyone and not two at a time

hence use one at a time instead of using two.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        closeClick : true,
        helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: when i type jQuery i get this `function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)} ` i already remove one but still i get the undefined function in line `$(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox`

Comment: Type jQuery("body").fancybox() and see

Comment: `jQuery("body").fancybox()` this line gets this `TypeError: undefined is not a functionmessage: "undefined is not a function"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: function Empty() {}<function scope>set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error`

Comment: May be you have to initialised or call in ready function or onload function

Comment: when calling script i use `$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({` what do you think of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery reference is not working which makes fancybox doesnt work.

Fix jQuery reference and everything should be alright